# Generating 2 random numbers with specific probabilities

Tags: matlab, random

I have earlier written a code that generates random number - 0 or 1 - that represents the outcome of a one toss, with the assumption that probability to have head or tail is 0.5 " equal probabilities".

Now I want to modify the code so that, it will represent a Bernolli trial. H - head- represents a success, and a variable p represents probability of success. 
I tried to search how to generate random number with specific probability however I didn't know exactly how it's done.

***My Earlier Code***

```
n = 1; %number of trials

% Generating a random number from 1 to n trials, logical condition <0.5
% indicates that function rand should generates only two outcomes,
% either 0 or 1.

% Let 1 indicates "H" and 0 indicates "T".
x = rand(1,n) <0.5;

% count how many H and T in each tossing trial
number_of_H =0 ; number_of_T  =0;

for n=1:n
    if(x(1,n)==1)
        number_of_H=number_of_H+1;
    end
    if(x(1,n)==0) 
        number_of_T = number_of_T+1;
    end
end

probability_H = number_of_H/n; 
probability_T = number_of_T/n;
```

I have seen this r = random(pd) from  [mathwork reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.truncatabledistribution.random.html) but when I tried to replace 0.7 with pd as a probability it gives an error that this is not a probability distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well there are two things. the reason you can't simply pass 0.7 into  `randompd` is because it expects the argument to be a probability distribution. not simply a number. To create a probability distribution look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/makedist.html)

But the code you have is actually useable! so thats exciting currently for a "fair coin" its .5 and .5 which you indicated in this line

```
x = rand(1,n) <0.5;
```

but for your knew biased coin you need something more like this

```
x = rand(1,n) <0.7;
```

hope that helps. Maybe you got the code from a teacher or something. but I will explain it. `rand(1,n)` generates a random number (from a uniform distribution on the interval 0 to 1) saying `<0.5` converts it to a logical value. true is 1 and 0 is false. so now you've converted your uniform distribution to a binary one using `0.5` as a threshold. for the weighted coin you want to use `0.7` for your threshold

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there, just change

```
x = rand(1,n) <0.5;
```

To

```
x = rand(1,n) < p;
```

And that's it. Since `rand` will produce numbers between 0 and 1 with equal probability, `1*p` of all those values will lie below `p` and therefore turn into a 1 (True), the rest is `>=p` and will turn into a 0 (False) which is exactly what you're looking for. Whether to use `<` or `<=` does not really matter, since the probability that you hit exactly `p` is almost 0. Same goes for producing exactly 0 or 1 using `rand`.